# Python typecasting string to int fails

Tags: python, integer, typeconverter

I get an error when I try to do a simple typecasting from string to integer in python (2.7):

```
year = device.time[year_pos:].strip() # This is '1993'
t = int(year) # Throws exception: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'int' referenced before assignment"
```

Why? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnboundLocalError` sounds as if you've assigned something to the name `int` in some other scope in your code (i.e., the code throwing the exception is inside a function, and you've used `int` as a name to store a variable in global code, or somewhere else).  There's [a blog post about `UnboundLocalError`](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python) where you can read more about this kind of problem, but for your issue, I'd just recommend not using builtin names to store variables.